# No problem: без проблем; нет проблем; не проблема, which one to use when?

Tags: разница

what is the difference between the 3, examples welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *standalone* phrase (usually an answer to a request), all three are very close in their meaning: "No problem!", although the 3rd variant "не проблема" is more like "Not *a* problem", and is usually given when the request is an inquiry about a problem.

Ex.: "Можешь меня сегодня подбросить?" - "Без проблем"/"Нет проблем" ("Can you give me a ride today?" - "No problem") and "Можешь меня сегодня подбросить? Но мне нужно пораньше." - "Не проблема" ("Can you give me a ride today? I need it at an earlier time." - "Not a problem")

As a phrase *in a sentence*, all three have a similar, but distinctively different meaning.

- без проблем - there were no problems/there would be no problems (the usual context is perfective)
- нет проблем - there are no problems (the usual context is imperfective)
- не проблема - [something] is not a problem

Comment: P.S. "нет проблем" can be turned into a perfective context (i. e. the end result of some actions) by adding "и" to it. "Настрой бэкап на своем телефоне, и нет проблем" / "Set up a backup on your phone, and that will be the end of your problems". "И нет проблем" is popular in colloquial speech, but not in literature.

Comment: "Без проблем" is literally translated to "without (any) problems" so you can use it without relation to a question: "Я восстановил свои данные без проблем" - "I restored my data without any problems"